# Reproduce Sequel's validates_min_length validation

Tags: ruby, sequel

I'm hoping to reproduce Sequel's `validates_min_length` errors for a Bcrypt-encrypted password.  I can't use the validation as it will test the password hash, rather than the un-encrypted text.

I'm having difficulty getting the `password=` method to produce the desired errors.

## Un-encrypted-password logic

```
require 'sequel'

DB = Sequel.sqlite

DB.create_table(:users) do
  primary_key :id
  String :name, null: false, unique: true
  String :password, null: false
end

class User < Sequel::Model
  plugin :validation_helpers

  def validate
    super
    validates_presence [:name,:password]
    validates_unique [:name]
    validates_min_length 8, :password
  end

end
```

IRB:

```
irb(main):001:0> u=User.new(name: 'foobar', password: 'Pa55w0rd')
=> #<User @values={:name=>"foobar", :password=>"Pa55w0rd"}>
irb(main):002:0> u.valid?
=> true
irb(main):003:0> u.password=nil
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> u
=> #<User @values={:name=>"foobar", :password=>nil}>
irb(main):005:0> u.valid?
=> false
irb(main):007:0> u.errors
=> {:password=>["is not present", "is shorter than 8 characters"]}
irb(main):008:0> u.password='foo'
=> "foo"
irb(main):009:0> u
=> #<User @values={:name=>"foobar", :password=>"foo"}>
irb(main):010:0> u.valid?
=> false
irb(main):011:0> u.errors
=> {:password=>["is shorter than 8 characters"]}
```

## Encrypted-password logic

```
require 'sequel'
require 'bcrypt'

DB = Sequel.sqlite

DB.create_table(:users) do
  primary_key :id
  String :name, null: false, unique: true
  String :password_hash, null: false
end

class User < Sequel::Model
  plugin :validation_helpers
  include BCrypt

  def validate
    super
    validates_presence [:name,:password]
    validates_unique [:name]
  end

  def password
    # check for :password_hash existence to ensure that validates_presence :password works correctly
    @password ||= Password.new(password_hash) if password_hash
  end

  def password=(new_password)

    # add validation errors
    errors.add(:password, 'is shorter than 8 characters') if new_password==nil || new_password.length < 8

    if new_password == nil
      @password = nil 
    else
      @password = Password.create(new_password)
    end

    self.password_hash = @password

  end

end
```

IRB:

```
irb(main):001:0> u=User.new(name: 'foobar', password: 'Pa55w0rd')
=> #<User @values={:name=>"foobar", :password_hash=>"$2a$10$K3UALPYz/bb5bdrGmbq22eRM31A6rU3kqkbzcU4.6J5APQVSqxQo6"}>
irb(main):002:0> u.valid?
=> true
irb(main):003:0> u.password=nil
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> u
=> #<User @values={:name=>"foobar", :password_hash=>nil}>
irb(main):005:0> u.valid?
=> false
irb(main):006:0> u.errors
=> {:password=>["is not present"]}
irb(main):007:0> u.password='foo'
=> "foo"
irb(main):009:0> u
=> #<User @values={:name=>"foobar", :password_hash=>"$2a$10$lA6fsKXSvl5cd.Zl53qEqOzxk1LPehvGujWaXwcf1//IUc82CmowC"}>
irb(main):008:0> u.valid?
=> true
```

Both invalid passwords (`nil`,'foo') are missing the `is shorter than 8 characters` error.

What am I missing?

Versions:

```
$ sequel --version
sequel 5.7.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as desired:

```
require 'sequel'
require 'bcrypt'

DB = Sequel.sqlite

DB.create_table(:users) do
  primary_key :id
  String :name, null: false, unique: true
  String :password_hash, null: false
end

class User < Sequel::Model
  plugin :validation_helpers
  include BCrypt

  def validate
    super
    validates_presence [:name,:password]
    validates_unique [:name]
    errors.add(:password, 'is shorter than 8 characters') if @password==nil || @password.length < 8
  end

  def password
    Password.new(password_hash) if password_hash
  end

  def password=(new_password)

    # uncomment to prevent bad passwords from changing a good password; probably needs to include a non-terminating error message
    # return if new_password==nil || new_password.length < 8

    # store clear-text password for validation
    @password = new_password

    #modify password hash accordingly
    self.password_hash = if new_password then Password.create(new_password) else nil end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

`@password` is not actually shorter than 8 characters.  BCrypt::Password is a subclass of string, and it will have the same length as the password hash.  You would have to set `@password` in `password=` if you wanted to use a validation to ensure the size of the password.

Comment: So, the `validates_min_length 8, :password` checks the `@password` instance variable, rather than calling the `password` reader method?

Comment: @craig the `password` method in your case returns the `@password` instance variable which is a `BCrypt::Password` or `nil` if there is no `password_hash`. Chances are if there is a truly valid answer for your question this gentleman would be able to provide it *Hint: look at who created the `Sequel` gem*

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure on functionality but this should work for you.

```
def validate
  super
  validates_presence [:name,:password]
  validates_unique [:name]
  validates_min_length 8, :password
end

def password=(new_password)
  return unless @password = new_password and @password.to_s.length >= 8
  self.password_hash = Password.create(password)
end
```

I added the actual length validation to validate so that `valid?` will return false. Additionally I cleaned up the `password=` method a bit.
So now `password=` has a guard clause that simply returns if the password is invalid as defined by "less than 8 characters". 
Otherwise we create a new password_hash via `Password.create` and assign it to `@password_hash`.

**Please note:** There is a functional change between my proposed code and yours which is that `@password_hash` is not overwritten when the "new_password" is invalid. This seemed counter intuitive to me that an invalid password could overwrite an existing and valid password_hash thus my change in implementation.

All that being said your best bet is actually to go with this

```
class User < Sequel::Model
  plugin :validation_helpers
  include BCrypt
  attr_accessor :password
  def validate
    super
    validates_presence [:name,:password]
    validates_unique [:name]
    validates_min_length 8, :password
  end

  def before_save
    self.password_hash = Password.create(password)
  end
end
```

This avoids all the manipulation and will only create a `password_hash` (which is all you actually need) if the model passes validation checks

Comment: your implementation doesn't work as you describe (I just tried it in IRB).  The 'too short' error is not added, perhaps because the password is not changed (allowing an invalid password to change a valid one).

Comment: it does pass validations, but it displays the unencrypted password.

Comment: @craig `@password` must be the `password` being validated for the validation to work correctly. if you hash the password it will always be > 8 characters you could manipulate the "display" value of `User` to mask the password if you'd like

Comment: I am aware of Jeremy's relationship to Sequel.